# Terminal space invaders?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, games, tui

I was just wondering if there was a command-line TUI space invaders game for Ubuntu? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

Comment: You've got too much free time, don't you?

Comment: Waaayyy too much. Like with this much, you could write it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `ninvaders` is the package you're looking for!

[image: Install via the software center]

You can simply install through the link above, your Software Center, or a terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ninvaders
```

Note that you must have the `universe` repository enabled.

[image: ninvaders screenshot]

Comment: Now I got a new time waster!  +1  =)

Comment: I had stuff to do today...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I need coffee. So, let's try this again...

Run `sudo apt-get install ninvaders` from the terminal (directions below) and let it install. Then, to start it, simply run `ninvaders` from the terminal and you don't get a big graphics filled screen and it won't scare the panda.

I'll include the original answer which is a GUI application. In case someone else is interested in playing the graphics version.

It's just your lucky day Paranoid Panda. Indeed such a critter exists and is simple to install and get running.

You can open your terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and, in there, type `sudo apt-get install open-invaders` and type your password. Your password will not show on the screen, will give no indicators like asterisks, and this is normal behaviour (but you know this, this is just to be complete).

After the installation is complete, in the same terminal window, type 'open-invaders' to start the game. The `-f` switch makes it open in a full screen. The `-w` switch makes it open in a windowed screen (sensible if you have dual screen).

You can read more about this game by going here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man6/open-invaders.6.html

Comment: This is no terminal user interface though! It's a full GUI application.

Comment: Well, firstly it's not a TUI command-line game (one with only text like the one in ByteCommander's answer), and secondly, it scared the willies out of me when it launched, filled my screen, and then I couldn't turn the volume down when it started talking to me! :D

Comment: My bad I need more coffee. Gimme a minute. I've seen another one in my travels. Will edit shortly assuming I find it again.